# How to place colors inside a text in React Native Text element?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to do something like:

```
<Text>A SMS will be sent to to +447 . Use 9999 to simulate it continue</Text>
```

But the +447 supposed to be in a different color. Something like this:

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest text elements with different styles:

```
<Text style={styles.pink}>
  A SMS will be sent to to <Text style={styles.black}>+447</Text> . Use 9999 to simulate it continue
</Text>
```